# How to add shared C# NuGet dependencies to a C++/Cli project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, nuget

Context: A Visual Studio solution with 2 assemblies, Cs and Cpp.

- Cs is a C# / .net45 dll
- Cpp is a C++/Cli dll, a C++ dll compiled with /clr.

I have some dependencies that are pure C# projects from nuget.org. I use the original packages provided by the authors. Adding them to the Cs project works fine, but not to Cpp.

How can I add the C# package to the C++ project?

Since it's C++/Cli, I can easily use .net objects, and I use e.g. in the C++ library stuff from the C# library. But somehow nuget only allows me to select C# projects to add a C# dependency to, not C++ /clr ones.

Comment: This NuGet issue is related: https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3665

Comment: Any progress?  This still appears to be an issue 4 years later in VS2017

Answer (score 1):

In your C++/CLI project, just add a reference (Menu->References->Add New Reference->Browse->Browse...) to the nlog.dll that nuget downloads to your [solutionfolder]/packages/nlog... folder. 
That seems to work for me.

Comment: This encodes the path (which includes the exact version) and needs to be updated manually later on.

Answer (score -1):

The way I've done it, is to make a "nugetmaster", which references all the nugets the other two projects will use. Build that one first, and reference the nuget assemblies manually within each project. Added bonus is to have more control on versions, only once place to update all other projects. And this scales well.

Another approach is similar to the one above - create a shared C# assembly used by them both, which also implements all the code using the nuget assemblies. And only expose wrappers.

Answer (score -2):

Please refer to NuGet documentation especially the "-IncludeReferencedProjects" parameter.

"From a project" section; http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package

Regards...

Comment: This would work if we were completely in C# land; this question is focused on C++/Cli and C# interop.

Comment: If you have vs project, it should work.This solution not depended with c#, the important thing is references of your project if you used project references correctly, it should work...

Comment: The basic issue is that C++ and C++/Cli projects default to native NuGet packages, while C# projects default to C# nuget packages. NuGet does not currently support adding a C# package to a native project.