# 32feet: could not install with nuget

Tags: c++, nuget, native, 32feet

I'm trying to install this library in an existing c++ project with NuGet, but the installation stops and give me the following message:

```
Could not install package '32feet.NET 3.5.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: You have hit the same problem as described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786338/how-to-add-shared-c-sharp-nuget-dependencies-to-a-c-cli-project

Answer (score 1):

Looks like NuGet currently doesn't support that:

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3665

https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3530

Comment: Could you explain the solution?

Comment: Add a Dummy C# project to your C++ solution, add all NuGet references you need to this dummy project. Then add these references as external to the C++ project. The Hint Path will Look like that: ..MySolution\packages\ThirdPartyPackageXY1.2.3.4\lib\net40\ThirdParty.dll     

Remaining Problem: -> If you update the Packages in Dummy Project, you have to update the HintPaths in C++ project by Hand (or script or something else)