# How do I create a NuGet package for a C++/CLI using MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, c++-cli

I've read [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893161/create-nuget-package-for-c-cli-mixed-assembly) for creating NuGet packages for C++/CLI .vcxproj projects using a .nuspec file. However, I'd like to use MSBuild to create my package instead of using a .nuspec file. I've seen [these instructions](https://lunarfrog.com/blog/how-to-use-msbuild15-net-framework) for packaging .NET Framework projects using MSBuild, but I haven't been able to find anything for doing the same with .vcxproj files.

Answer (score 2):

MSBuild can `pack` a Visual Studio project into a NuGet package, but [only if that project uses PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-msbuild) instead of packages.config.

As of this writing, [the Visual Studio UI doesn't allow you to choose PackageReference](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/use-packagereference-in-vcxproj/351636) instead of packages.config as the NuGet package configuration mechanic for VCXPROJ files. However, you can manually edit the `.vcxproj` file and convert it to PackageReference format.

### Edit .vcxproj

By default, `.vcxproj` files are not SDK-style projects (I don't know if they can even be converted to SDK-style projects). To build NuGet packages from non-SDK-style projects, you'll need to enable managed package reference support and add [reference NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-msbuild#add-the-nugetbuildtaskspack-package).

#### Enable Managed Package Reference Support

Add the following to your .vcxproj (inside the `<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">` element):

```
<EnableManagedPackageReferenceSupport>true</EnableManagedPackageReferenceSupport>
```

#### Reference NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack

Add the following to your .vcxproj (inside the `Project` element):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack">
      <Version>5.11.0</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

#### Further Configuration

Add any other packages your project depends on. Notice the `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` element. You need `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack` to pack your project, but you don't want it as a dependency when others try and install your NuGet package. Adjust the version for `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack` as appropriate.

If your project references static libraries, you don't want those included as NuGet package dependencies. Use the `PrivateAssets` element to exclude them. I.e:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\vendor\static-lib-build\static-lib\static-lib.vcxproj">
      <Project>{8aa99891-3ff7-3fa7-b1b5-131664298a26}</Project>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Also add the following inside the `Project` element"

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageId>Your.Package.Id</PackageId>
    <Authors>Your Name</Authors>
    <BuildOutputTargetFolder>lib</BuildOutputTargetFolder>
    <PackageDescription>A description of this package.</PackageDescription>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

What's in the `TargetFramework` element should [correspond](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) to what's in the `TargetFrameworkVersion` element elsewere in your project.

Note that I haven't covered building a cross-platform NuGet package. By its very nature, C++/CLI projects are targeted to a specific processor / architecture. You can include native libraries for multiple architectures in the `runtime` directory of your NuGet package, but I don't cover that here.

### Restore, Build, and Pack Using MSBuild

This line will restore your NuGet packages, build the project, and then pack it:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" path\to\the_project.vcxproj /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:ProductVersion=1.0.0.69 /t:Restore;Build /t:pack
```

Change the command line options to suit your needs. You may need to run this command twice if `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack` hasn't already been restored.