# C++ CLR NuGet Package Error: Installation Failed

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, clr, nuget-package

So I'm using C++ to work on a project and I've created a GUI. I tried to use NuGet to instead a package However, it keeps bringing up this error:

```
Could not install package 'MetroModernUI 1.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I found a link on here to help me fix this issue. However another issue came up on step 2. Here is the link and error:

[How can I make my managed NuGet package support C++/CLI projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694947/how-can-i-make-my-managed-nuget-package-support-c-cli-projects)

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'NuGet.CommandLine.5.8.1' does not exist in project 'Project Name'
Package 'NuGet.CommandLine.5.8.1' does not exist in folder '<path>\packages'
```

A Package folder doesn't even exist in that directory. Someone please help me because that error also came up in the previous error when trying to instead a package using NuGet, here it is:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'MetroModernUI.1.4.0' does not exist in project 'Project Name'
Package 'MetroModernUI.1.4.0' does not exist in folder '<path>\packages'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps**

**1**Frist, install [NuGet.CommandLine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.CommandLine/4.7.3?_src=template) version `4.7.3` into your clr project by **Nuget Package Manager UI**.

**2)** after that, add this manually under the new created `packages.config` file

```
<package id="MetroModernUI" version="1.4.0"/>
```

**Then**, rebuild your project to restore the nuget package `MetroModernUI`.

**And** you can find the nuget package is installed into your project under `<Solution_Folder>\packages\MetroModernUI.1.4.0.0`

**3)** then right-click on **References**-->**Add Reference**-->**Browse** and then add

`<Solution_Folder>\packages\MetroModernUI.1.4.0.0\lib\net\MetroFramework.dll` or any others in that folder.

You should note that clr project cannot reference net assembly dlls automatically by nuget. You should add them manually.

**All of these steps** will help you get what you want.